# Spring SimpleThreadScope does not support descruction callbacks

Tags: spring, maven, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I would like to run parallel selenium tests (using webriver and the Spring JUnit runner). Webdriver is a spring bean with the custom thread scope. But I get a following warning `SimpleThreadScope does not support descruction callbacks` So the browsers are not closed. Any idea how to close them (more precisely call the quit method)?

spring config

```xml
<bean id="threadScope" class="org.springframework.context.support.SimpleThreadScope" />

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
    <property name="scopes">
           <map>
               <entry key="thread" value-ref="threadScope" />
           </map>
       </property>
</bean>

<bean id="webDriver" class="org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver" scope="thread" destroy-method="quit">
    <constructor-arg name="remoteAddress" value="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub" />
    <constructor-arg name="desiredCapabilities" ref="browserAgent" />
</bean>
```

maven config

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.class</include>
        </includes>
        <reportsDirectory>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
        <parallel>classes</parallel>
        <threadCount>2</threadCount>
        <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This post http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/custom-thread-scope-module-code-example.html suggests a custom Thread implementations. But where is an extension point type of Runnable using any JUnit runner?

```java
public class ThreadScopeRunnable implements Runnable {

    protected Runnable target = null;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public ThreadScopeRunnable(Runnable target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    /**
     * Runs <code>Runnable</code> target and 
     * then afterword processes thread scope 
     * destruction callbacks.
     */
    public final void run() {
        try {
            target.run();
        } finally {
            ThreadScopeContextHolder.currentThreadScopeAttributes().clear();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice -- good to know I'm not the only one trying to run Selenium from JUnit. And also, perhaps running from multiple webdrivers as well.

Comment: @banterCZ, Im not able to follow the solution for this question. Im stuck exactly in same place as mentioned in question. Could you let me know if you have pushed code with solution in github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here there is a workaround, not perfect solution, because it blocks browsers until the end of all tests.

You have to create a register of thread scope beans which handles their destruction.

```
public class BeanRegister {

    private Set<CustomWebDriver> beans= new HashSet<CustomWebDriver>();

    public void register(CustomWebDriver bean) {
        beans.add(bean);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void clean() {
        for (CustomWebDriver bean : beans) {
            bean.quit();
        }
    }

}
```

Config it as singleton.

```
<bean class="BeanRegister" />
```

You have to write a class extending RemoteWebDriver.

```
public class CustomWebDriver extends RemoteWebDriver {

    @Autowired
    private BeanRegister beanRegister;

    @PreConstruct
    public void init() {
        beanRegister.register(this);
    }

}
```

That's it.